# font-weight is not working properly --> css

Tags: html, css, text-styling

I am trying to change the font weight of a paragraph in CSS. I have tried thin, bold, normal, 700, 800, 900, but the appearance is not changing.

```css
.p1 {
  font-weight: thin;
}
```

```html
<p>It was the best of times, it was the worst of times</p>

<p class="p1">It was the best of times, it was the worst of times</p>
```

Comment: Could you provide the HTML please

Comment: Also which font is being used and does it have a `thin` variant loaded?

Comment: *"There are generally limited weights available for a particular font family. When a specified weight doesn't exist, a nearby weight is used. "* - MDN

Comment: it's depending on which font you use, Some have only one font-weight property and doesn't allow more.

Answer (score 0):

Browser default fonts typically only support one or two weights. So you need to find a webfont which does support multiple weights, for example, [Noto Sans](https://fonts.google.com/noto/specimen/Noto+Sans?query=noto%20sans).

Some webfonts are available from public CDNs, others you need to host yourself. In either case, you need to add the `@font-face` rules to your stylesheet. With Google’s CDN, you import these rules from an endpoint which looks like this:

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Noto+Sans:ital,wght@0,100;0,200;0,300;0,400;0,500;1,100;1,200;1,300;1,400;1,500&display=swap');
```

Then you can use the various weights of font in your page.

```css
 @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Noto+Sans:ital,wght@0,100;0,200;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;0,800;0,900;1,100;1,200;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700;1,800;1,900&display=swap');
 
p {
  font-family: 'Noto Sans'
} 
.p1, .p1i {
  font-weight: 100;
}
.p2, .p2i {
  font-weight: 200;
}
.p3, .p3i {
  font-weight: 300;
}
.p4, .p4i {
  font-weight: 400;
}
.p5, .p5i {
  font-weight: 500;
}
.p1i, .p2i, .p3i, .p4i, .p5i {
  font-style: italic;
}
```

```html
<p class="p1">It was the best of times, it was the worst of times</p>
<p class="p1i">It was the best of times, it was the worst of times</p>
<p class="p2">It was the best of times, it was the worst of times</p>
<p class="p2i">It was the best of times, it was the worst of times</p>
<p class="p3">It was the best of times, it was the worst of times</p>
<p class="p3i">It was the best of times, it was the worst of times</p>
<p class="p4">It was the best of times, it was the worst of times</p>
<p class="p4i">It was the best of times, it was the worst of times</p>
<p class="p5">It was the best of times, it was the worst of times</p>
<p class="p5i">It was the best of times, it was the worst of times</p>
```

Answer (score -1):

I think the `font-weight` property in CSS usually accepts numeric values or keywords, i.e.,

```css
.paragraph {
    font-weight: 100; 
}
```